# Docker Compose: Mock external services

Tags: networking, docker

I have the following situation:

My application consists of a single web service that calls an 
external API (say, some SaaS service, ElasticSearch or so). For non-unit-testing purposes we want to control the external service and later also inject faults. The application and the "mocked" API are dockerized and 
now I want to use `docker-compose` to spin all containers up.

Because the application has several addresses hardcoded (e.g. the hostname of external services) I cannot change them and need to work around.

The `service` container makes a call to `http://external-service.com/getsomestuff`.

My idea was to use some features that are provided by docker to reroute all outgoing traffic to the external `http://external-service.com/getsomestuff` to the mock container without changing the URL.

My `docker-compose.yaml` looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  service:
    build: ./service
    container_name: my-service1
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: /bin/sh -c "python3 app.py"

  api:
    build: ./api-mock
    container_name: my-api-mock
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    command: /bin/sh -c "python3 app.py"
```

Finally, I have a driver that just does the following:

```
curl -XGET localhost:5000/
curl -XPUT localhost:5001/configure?delay=10
curl -XGET localhost:5000/
```

where the second `curl` just sets the delay in the mock to 10 seconds.

There are several options I have considered:

- Using `iptables`-fu (would require modifying Dockerfiles to install it)
- Using docker networks (this is really unclear to me)

Is there any simple option to achieve what I want?

*Edit*:

For clarity, here is the relevant part of the `service` code:

```
import requests

@app.route('/')
def do_stuff():
    r = requests.get('http://external-service.com/getsomestuff')
    return process_api_response(r.text())
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker runs an internal DNS server for user defined networks. Any unknown host lookups are forwarded to you normal DNS servers.

Version 2+ compose files will automatically create a network for compose to use so there's a number of ways to control the hostnames it resolves.

The simplest way is to name your container with the hostname:

```
version: "2"
services:
  external-service.com:
    image: busybox
    command: sleep 100
  ping:
    image: busybox
    command: ping external-service.com
    depends_on:
      - external-service.com
```

If you want to keep container names you can use [`links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

```
version: "2"
services:
  api:
    image: busybox
    command: sleep 100
  ping:
    image: busybox
    links:
      - api:external-service.com
    command: ping external-service.com
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Or network [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases)

```
version: "2"
services:
  api:
    image: busybox
    command: sleep 100
    networks:
      pingnet:
        aliases:
        - external-service.com
  ping:
    image: busybox
    command: ping external-service.com
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - pingnet
networks:
  pingnet:
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what the problem is you're trying to solve, but if you're trying to make `external-service.com` inside the container direct traffic to your "mock" service, I think you should be able to do that using the [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extrahosts) directive in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  For example, if I have this:

```
version: "2"

services:
  example:
    image: myimage
    extra_hosts:
      - google.com:172.23.254.1
```

That will result in `/etc/hosts` in the container containing:

```
172.23.254.1    google.com
```

And attempts to access `http://google.com` will hit my web server at 172.23.254.1.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with -links, is there a way to do networks in docker-compose?

version: '3'

services:

```
MOCK:
 image: api-mock:latest
 container_name: api-mock-container
 ports:
    - "8081:80"

api: 
 image: my-service1:latest
 links:
   - MOCK:external-service.com
```